# CATS plugin messing up VRM textures

Tags: texturing

So, I made this model in [VRoid Studio](https://vroid.com/en) earlier, and tried to bring it into blender using the [CATS](https://github.com/absolute-quantum/cats-blender-plugin) plugin. For some reason, after I click "auto fix" it seems to be putting all the textures in the wrong places.

Does anybody know how I can fix this?
[image]

Comment: Not knowing anything about the softwares, I can say that if the system didn’t entirely EAT the UV maps, you can probably fix this with a little material re-assignment, or possibly some UV map input nodes, or maybe even translating some UV islands by some increment (usually steps of 1).

Comment: Can you maybe walk me through one of those solutions? I'm really new to blender, and have no idea how to actually do all those things

Comment: It seems like you may have bitten off more than you can chew. I recommend reading the Blender Manual, particularly the sections Rendering -> Materials and then right after it Rendering -> Shader Nodes for a more thorough understanding of how blender materials work. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/index.html Here also is the page on UVs https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/uv/index.html That should help lay some groundwork, and you might figure the rest out yourself. If you are still stuck after that, though, I’ll be glad to help you. :-)

Comment: Thanks, this might help a bit. I'll stark tinkering with it once I have the time. I'll let you know if I figured it out

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well and spent literally all day trying to fix it.

Finally solved the problem and the answer is to download blender 2.92 and use that older version instead of 3.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the textures around until the texures go where they're supposed to and rename the materials.